# Task_disconnected_while_still_running

Tags: c#, file-upload, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I have a windows phone 8.1 Rt app that uses the Background Uploader and downloader classes extensively. I have done good amount of testing and updated the app in the store. According to the data in the failure log in the dev centre, the app is crashing a lot for the end users. Unfortnately the log provided in the dev centre has no additonal details and has no useful stack trace.

Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Hiding,*targetState*=_Inactive.

This is all the information i have about the crash. I have tried implementing log, wraping all major functions in try catch blocks and limiting the number of items in the backgroundUploader class but the crashes are just not reducing. Ididn't find any help on the developer forums as well.

Please throw some light on what exactly causes such a crash and how to handle this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your sure this is a crash not a hang?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all unhandled exceptions from within the `App.xaml.cs` class where you subscribe the to `UnhandledException` event in the constructor:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    }

    protected override void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Optionally use e.Handled = true;

        // Send to Google Ananlytics
    }
```

The line `e.Handled=true` will prevent your app from crashing, but it is not recommended to use because probably your app will no longer be in a usable state after the exception occurs.

In my projects I use `Google Analytics` for logging all my exceptions.

Comment: Hi Kristian, I did subscribe to the unhandled exception as well. But since i haven't integrated it to google Analytics yet, i am logging it in a local file which the user can send as a part of the error report. But nothing is added into that file as well. So i'm assuming it was not caught there. Is there any other way to find out what is going wrong?